# Configure Branch SDK with Landing page, track attribution through install

Tags: branch.io, attribution

Can the Branch SDK track installs to the inviting user through an intermediate landing page?

In my Unity based game I'm setting up a social share button on the game's splash page. When the user share's the game with someone by default the branch SDK would send the invited prospect directly to the Apple app store to install the app. Instead I want to send the prospect to a Landing page so that we can A/B test content and optimize installs.

Thus I want to track install/play back to the original inviting user. Is this possible? If so, how is it configured.

TIA,

~eric

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by setting custom link properties when you create the share link. For example, you can set $fallback_url as a link property when creating the linkproperties object

```
linkProperties.controlParams.Add("$fallback_url", "http://example.com");
```

When you use this with [sharelink](https://docs.branch.io/apps/unity/#share-deep-link) the link created will navigate to the fallback_url instead of the app / play store.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, a fallback link isn't what I'm looking for. I'm looking for tracking from invite to install through the intermediate landing page. It appears that this is possible by using the Branch "Journeys" functionality. Though this is a paid feature...

Comment: you can also use the Branch web sdk on the landing page. Use the SDK to read the referring link. Dynamically generate the 'download' button adding parameters from the original link